# Database: How to properly construct database with one of its table has fields with multiple values

Tags: sql, database

Hi guys i am working with database right now and i'm having some issue about fields with multiple value. i have a table name "jobs" and i have a field "required_skills" from the field name it self its obvious the the value should be at least more than one(skills). but i am also aware that i am violating the atomicity of a field, so i tried to separate the "required skills" to another table which has a field of `id`, `jobID(FK)`, `skills`.

But my problem now is `skills` field will also store multiple value so it doesnt change anything. can someone help me with this issue? thanks and have a good day

Comment: Please read up about third normal form

Answer (score 0):

It's called a many to many relationship. You want 3 tables:

```
skills (skillid, skill)
jobs (jobid)
job_skills (jobid, skillid)
```

For each job, there are multiple job_skills rows.